# Generate C code for sympy expression "e1 op e2" where op is an arithmetic comparison operator

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I have a *sympy* expression

```
e1 op e2
```

where `op` is any arithmetic comparison operator, such as `<, >, <=`, etc.

I want to generate a C code

```
double f(double x1,double x2,..., double xn){
  if (e1 op e2) return 0 else return 1;
}
```

where x1,...,x2 are the free variables in either e1 or e2. 
Can I use *sympy.printing.ccode*, or *sympy.utlilities.codegen* to simplify this code generation?

Comment: You can do this with Piecewise currently, I opened a PR for supporting ITE too: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/10209

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe you can explain on this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using [ccode](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.ccode.ccode) and [Piecewise](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html?highlight=piecewise#sympy.functions.elementary.piecewise.Piecewise) (you would need to provide the function body as a template):

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, Piecewise, ccode
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
>>> e1 = x + 2
>>> e2 = y - 5
>>> rel = e1 < e2
>>> pw = Piecewise((0, rel), (1, True))
>>> print(ccode(pw, assign_to=z))
if (x + 2 < y - 5) {
   z = 0;
}
else {
   z = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  What do you mean by "provide a function body as  a template"? It seems codeGen (not ccode) of sympy can generate the whole function, including the body. Right?

Comment: @zell, yes it does. I haven't tried for this particular example though.